# Rails: Nothing produced by 3.times { model1.model2.build }

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following along with this [Rails tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) describing how to do nested model forms. At 4:32, he starts describing how to prepopulate the form with three empty models. The two models in question are:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :positions, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :positions
end
```

And...

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event
end
```

In my events controller, I added the tutorial's code to the `new` method

```
def new
  @event = Event.new
  3.times { @event.positions.build }
end
```

And my event's form view is populated too.

```
<!-- /apps/views/events/_form.html.erb -->

<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <h3>Event Details</h3>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <!-- more fields here -->

  <h3>Create positions for the event</h3>
  <% f.fields_for :positions do |builder| %>
    <p>
      <%= builder.label :name %>
      <%= builder.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <!-- more fields here -->
  <% end %>

  <!-- more fields here -->
<% end %>
```

However, the `position` fields don't appear on my form. I've `rake db:migrated` and restarted the server (`Ctrl-C`, `rake s`) a bunch of times with no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `@event.positions.build` a method? How about `@event.positions.build()`?

Comment: Is an ActiveRecord method. In Ruby you don't need ().

Comment: The railscast didnt have the parens. I added them and it didn't affect anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed attr_accessible stuff.

In your Event model add:

```
attr_accessible :positions_attributes
```

Take a look at this example:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :addresses_attributes, :birth_date, :email, :gender, :name, :vat_number
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
  #  validates_uniqueness_of :vat_number
  paginates_per 50

  def gender=(gender)
    gender = gender.downcase
    case gender.downcase
    when 'm'
      gender = 'male'
    when 'f'
      gender = 'female'
    else
    end
    write_attribute(:gender, gender)
  end
end


class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :country, :postal_code, :street, :contact
  belongs_to :contact
end
```

Also, since you are following that tutorial, you'll probably will stop at the helpers. Here are an working version as rails 3.2.13:

```
  def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)
    f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)", :class => "icon-remove")
  end

  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
  end
```

And the javascript helpers:

```
function remove_fields(link) {
    $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
    $(link).closest(".fields").hide();
}

function add_fields(link, association, content) {
    var new_id = new Date().getTime();
    var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
    $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
    $(link).parent().append('<input type="hidden" name="click" value="true" />');
    $("#last_id").val(new_id);
}
```

Comment: I wasn't using the `attr_accessible` in the first place. I tried adding it but it didnt make a difference. The rest of the code looks interesting. Is that for adding new child models with javascript?

Comment: I ended up going with the new v4 strong parameters instead and that ended up working. thanks! `params.require(:event).permit(... , positions_attributes: [:id,:name,:description] )`